# Is it possible with Electron to load a TypeScript file directly?

Tags: typescript, electron, content-security-policy

Is it possible with Electron to load a TypeScript file directly without having to use `tsc` separately? Similar to how `ts-node` allows us to run ts code directly without having to do `tsc` + `node` individually.

It could work like this:

```
<script type="text/typescript" src="script.ts"></script>

<script type="text/typescript">
  let a : number = 1
  console.log(a)
</script>
```

In fact, while looking around, I found this: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-script

However, I couldn't make this work in Electron so far. Perhaps because I need to tweak the Content Security Policy somehow? And if yes, how? Or change something else?

And yes, I know it might be inefficient for larger projects to do this, but for my usecase, compiling on the fly is okay because the project is small and I just want to do fast prototyping without the complication of an added compilation step.

Answer (score 1):

There is precedent like `electron-compile` https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-compile and you'll notice it is non trivial job: there are lot of edge case you need to handle and even after that there'll be unexpected side effect occurs. Though you can technically try, I would not recommend.